# Spinner drop down popup position changes in Nexus 5 (android 5.0)

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a Spinner in my app. I used the basic spinner and this is my code:`

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/SpinnerSpinnerTheme"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/hj_order_date_spinner"
    />`
```

and this is how i instantiated in my activity

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.hj_spinner_items,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dateSpinner.setPrompt("Sort By");
    dateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works fine in android 4.4.4 but on Nexus 5(using Lollipop) the drop down list/Popup changes it's position and hides the "Sort By" bar or the original spinner.
Can anyone provide any insight as to what might be the issue?

Comment: Please explain the issue that you're seeing in more detail. The position changes in what way?

Comment: the popup covers the original spinner.
It's top should be aligned the bottom of the Spinner View but in Nexus 5 it's top is aligned with the top of the Spinner View, so the spinner prompt text is hidden behind the popup window.

Comment: That's how spinners are supposed to look when using the Material theme. You can set android:overlapAnchor="false" if you don't want it to look like a Material spinner.

Comment: It worked.
Please make that a formal answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify whether the spinner drop-down should overlap the anchor by using the `android:overlapAnchor` attribute. When using the Material spinner style, this attribute defaults to `true`.

```
<Spinner
    ...
    android:overlapAnchor="false" />
```

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to make it work like on G+ ? so that the window will take the entire width? If so, please answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31773105/878126

Comment: How do you get this effect pre-lollipop? it seems not to effect previous OS versions.