# Spinner overlap

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to create a spinner like google is using in his contacts app.
So I created a spinner, and everything works, but there is one problem:
The dropdown menu of the spinner overlaps the spinner item itself:
How can I fix this, so that the items shows below the spinner.

[image]

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/main_controller_spinner"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:overlapAnchor="true">

</Spinner>
```

Comment: Maybe this is the answer that you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924230/spinner-drop-down-popup-position-changes-in-nexus-5-android-5-0

I also saw some solutions where people wrap the TextView from the spinner item with a LinearLayout, so maybe you can give it a try as well.

Comment: No won't work. Same issue. Error exists also in Android 4.4

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
android:overlapAnchor="false"
```

Comment: This should do it.